# Power spectrum enhancement in primodial black hole

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

To produce a primordial Black Hole in in the inflationary epoch, there should be enhancement in the power spectrum. Both the slow roll approximation and exact solution show this feature. My question how to convert the spectrum in wave number, k. I want to show the enhancement in k. In slow roll approximation the spectrum proportional to  $V^3/V'^2$, where V is the inflationary potential. How to convert it in K.